# CSS opacity issue on hover

Tags: html, css

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vbtts/2624/
This is the html:

```
    <a href="#" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 big-container with-background">
        <div class="bottom-align">
            <label class="uppercase">preséntation</label>
            <h2>Une entreprise<br> intégrée pour<br> contrôler la qualité<br> de toutes les étapes<br> des projets></h2>
        </div>
   </a>
```

and the css:

```
.with-background{width:100%;background:url(https://cask.scotch.io/2015/04/scotch-box-sidebar.png);display:block;height:200px;}
.with-background:hover{opacity:0.7}
```

What i want to achieve on hover state is to do an opacity on the background image, but NOT on the text (on label and h2). How can i do that ? Thx

Comment: technically, this is not possible the way you put it down like that, You need to detach your label code from the container, sadly, cause there is not a nice way to influence the `.uppercase h2` without not affecting the background. So better to detach your content from your background by not nesting it in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your jsfiddle,
use a before or after element

```
.with-background{
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  height:200px;
  position: relative;
}
.with-background:before{
  width:100%;
  background:url(https://cask.scotch.io/2015/04/scotch-box-sidebar.png);
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  content: " "; 
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.with-background:hover:before{opacity:0.2}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vbtts/2635/

if however you what to avoid negative z-index you may also do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vbtts/2640/

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You have got two different solutions:

### 1) Make the png background image 0.7 opacity in Photoshop/GIMP and put wit a black background:

```
 .background {
      background: url(your-semitransp.png) #000;
 }
 .background:hover {
      background-color: transparent;
 }
```

With this mode you can emulate the opacity to 100% with the `#000` background color, and in hover remove it to make the background semitransparent.

### 2) Two different divs:

If you write a similar structure:

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="background"></div>
   <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

You can put background in absolute positioning and text above it.

```
 .wrap { position : relative; }
 .background {
     position :absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 0;
 }
 .text {
     position :absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 1;
 }
 .wrap:hover .background{ 
     opacity: 0.7;
 }
```

### The `::after`  or `::before` solution:

I can achieve that with your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vbtts/2632/

But I hate negative z-index, so I can't recommend you to make that.

Comment: the second option should be your best shot, because technically when you use the first option, you use bandwith for loading the second picture. For a  mobile website this would not be smart. Thinking out of optimizing your pictures there and the flow of the load of your website.

Comment: No no no, there aren't second picture. There are only one, the trick is in the background color

Comment: a css only solution is possible see my answer, why do we even assume he can alter the HTML?

Comment: See the end of my answer. I make it too, but it's neccesary a negative z-index, that's dangerous, that's weird, and in my opinion that's a crap. Even it's incompatible with some versions of IE and in some old android devices. So I can't recommend negative z-index

Comment: if you have an alery to negative z-index there is a solution to that as well :D
http://jsfiddle.net/Vbtts/2640/

Comment: The max value of a z-index is `2147483647` so there are so many posibilities in positive values to need to make a negative value

Comment: It's not alergy, it's common sense.

Comment: I make that in my fiddle but it was not working, weird thing. The text in my fiddle was positioning below the background. I'm confused, I will research about your changes. Thank you!

Comment: well negative z-index has it's uses as it effectively pushes the item "under" the document... not clickable etc but I do get your point. (aslo tthe nex time I see some noob writing z-index = 2147483647 i'll know where he read it :D:D:D)

Comment: LOL. I don't achieve never max z-index of 100000, but it's because I write 100 by 100 (z-index:100, the next z-index:200, etc), by this way, I have 99 positions if I need it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS property background-opacity, but you can fake it by inserting a pseudo element with regular opacity the exact size of the element behind it. When using this method, altering the HTML is not needed.

```
.with-background::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(https://cask.scotch.io/2015/04/scotch-box-sidebar.png);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}

.with-background:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

I updated your jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Vbtts/2625/

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

Answer (score 0):

Opacity affects children, so what you want is difficult to achieve with opacity.

A workaround would be to add a gradient with rgba to the background image. This is effectively an invisible image overlay that is shown on hover.

Invisible layer:

```
 .with-background {  
                  background: linear-gradient(
                              rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 
                              rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) ), 
                              url('https://cask.scotch.io/2015/04/scotch-box-sidebar.png');
}
```

Opacity added on hover:

```
.with-background:hover {
                 background: linear-gradient(
                             rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 
                             rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)), 
                             url('https://cask.scotch.io/2015/04/scotch-box-sidebar.png') ;
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5gnk28ah/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should use absolute positioning. Using it you could place the image behind the text without wrapping it.

I've change your fiddle as follow:

```
<a href="#" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 big-container">
  <div class="with-background"></div>div>
    <div class="bottom-align">
                            <label class="uppercase">preséntation</label>
                            <h2>Une entreprise<br> intégrée pour<br> contrôler la qualité<br> de toutes les       étapes<br> des projets></h2>
                        </div>

                    </a>
```

CSS:

```
.with-background{width:100%;background:url(https://cask.scotch.io/2015/04/scotch-box-sidebar.png);display:block;height:200px; position: absolute; }
.with-background:hover{opacity:0.7}
.bottom-align {position: absolute; }
```

I hope that it shows you the way how do it :)